In react, without hooks, why some variables change as the state they rely on changes?
I'm new to React.js, and when I was learning from the official website I was confused by how the below code works.
As you can see, I modified the code in the web, and named a new variable 'temp', and I'm puzzled that it changes as the variable 'filterText' changes.
How this happens and why? I supposed that this is because 'temp' is directly computed from 'filterText', but I want to know the root of this.
import { useState } from 'react';

function FilterableProductTable({ products }) {
  const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState('');
  const [inStockOnly, setInStockOnly] = useState(false);
  const temp = filterText[0];

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchBar
        filterText={filterText}
        inStockOnly={inStockOnly}
        onFilterTextChange={setFilterText}
        onInStockOnlyChange={setInStockOnly} />
      <ProductTable
        products={products}
        filterText={filterText}
        inStockOnly={inStockOnly} />
      {temp}
    </div>
  );
}

function ProductCategoryRow({ category }) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <th colSpan="2">
        {category}
      </th>
    </tr>
  );
}

function ProductRow({ product }) {
  const name = product.stocked ? product.name :
    <span style={{ color: 'red' }}>
      {product.name}
    </span>;

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{name}</td>
      <td>{product.price}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

function ProductTable({ products, filterText, inStockOnly }) {
  const rows = [];
  let lastCategory = null;

  products.forEach((product) => {
    if (
      product.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(
        filterText.toLowerCase()
      ) === -1
    ) {
      return;
    }
    if (inStockOnly && !product.stocked) {
      return;
    }
    if (product.category !== lastCategory) {
      rows.push(
        <ProductCategoryRow
          category={product.category}
          key={product.category} />
      );
    }
    rows.push(
      <ProductRow
        product={product}
        key={product.name} />
    );
    lastCategory = product.category;
  });

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

function SearchBar({
  filterText,
  inStockOnly,
  onFilterTextChange,
  onInStockOnlyChange
}) {
  return (
    <form>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={filterText} placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => onFilterTextChange(e.target.value)} />
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={inStockOnly}
          onChange={(e) => onInStockOnlyChange(e.target.checked)} />
        {' '}
        Only show products in stock
      </label>
    </form>
  );
}

const PRODUCTS = [
  {category: "Fruits", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Apple"},
  {category: "Fruits", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Dragonfruit"},
  {category: "Fruits", price: "$2", stocked: false, name: "Passionfruit"},
  {category: "Vegetables", price: "$2", stocked: true, name: "Spinach"},
  {category: "Vegetables", price: "$4", stocked: false, name: "Pumpkin"},
  {category: "Vegetables", price: "$1", stocked: true, name: "Peas"}
];

export default function App() {
  return <FilterableProductTable products={PRODUCTS} />;
}


I tried some variables computed with a state without putting them in any hook functions, and they seem to all change as the state itself changes. I want to know what led to this.
Failed to find a related explanation on the web (I might just don't know how to describe this), and I really appreciate any replies. thx.

When you call setFilterText or setInStockOnly, React schedules a re-render of the FilterableProductTable component. This is because useState hooks manage state, and updating state triggers a re-render of the component in which the state resides.
Since temp is computed from filterText, and filterText is a state variable, temp will be recalculated with the current value of filterText each time the component re-renders. Therefore, whenever filterText changes, temp is updated to reflect the first character of the new filterText.
 const temp = filterText[0]; // This is recomputed every render


Thank you for the answer! But I'm still slightly confused about what kinds of computations from state variables will be recalculated. Like temp, it is directly sliced from the state variable. Then what else? Or how to know or define this kind of computation? I'm curious about the mechanism here.
